# Spring Boot microservices Volumes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

I have some experience creating microservices architectured projects using docker and PHP APIs,

Now I migrated to the spring boot framework to build a microservices project.

The question that I have is how do I manage to create volumes and mount them in the  corresponding containers knowing that java is a compiled programming language so even if a mount the `.jar` file build from maven it will be deprecated as soon as commit a change in the host repository.

Is there any way to create a workflow like building the `.jar` file, mount it to the container and within the container build the new release as transparent as possible?

Comment: Have you seen https://maven.fabric8.io/?

Comment: Why mounting the `.jar` in a volume? Why not create an image for each version of your application?